# Is there any difference between gdal_proximity.py and ArcGIS Euclidean Distance?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gdal, distance

The gdal_proximity.py [description](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_proximity.html) says:

> The gdal_proximity.py script generates a raster proximity map
>   indicating the distance from the center of each pixel to the center of
>   the nearest pixel identified as a target pixel. Target pixels are
>   those in the source raster for which the raster pixel value is in the
>   set of target pixel values.

While, regarding Euclidean Distance, ArcGIS [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/understanding-euclidean-distance-analysis.htm) says:

> Conceptually, the Euclidean algorithm works as follows: for each cell, 
>   the distance to each source cell is determined by calculating the
>   hypotenuse with x_max and y_max as the other two legs of the triangle.
>   This calculation derives the true Euclidean distance, rather than the
>   cell distance. The shortest distance to a source is determined, and if
>   it is less than the specified maximum distance, the value is assigned
>   to the cell location on the output raster.

Is there any real difference between these algorithms?

Comment: Lots of arc's heavy lifting is done with gdal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [commented by @Matte](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199735/is-there-any-difference-between-gdal-proximity-py-and-arcgis-euclidean-distance#comment302881_199735):

> Conceptually no , as the ArcGIS documentaion says. Both calculate the
>   distance of the cell center. But usually you have different outputs
>   from different tools and programs depending on number types, precision
>   and rounding in the calculation process. To tell if this [matters]
>   you can only try it out and see if the small deviations really
>   concern.